# The multithreading problem of concurrent.futures in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, web-crawler, concurrent.futures

I am having problems running multithreaded with concurrent.futures, the code below I am fetching data from the web, if running a company (get_data) then no problem, however if taking multiple companies (get_data_all), can't run multithreading, please give me your opinion on this issue, thank you!

```
import requests, pandas as pd, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re,sys
import concurrent.futures as threads

company,page,check_final_page='DHG',0,False
Content_Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
User_Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'
def get_data(company,page):
    df=pd.DataFrame({})
    send_param=\
f'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24scriptmanager=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24panelAjax%7Cctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24pager2&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24pager2&__EVENTARGUMENT={page}&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTU2NzY0ODUyMGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFKGN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkY3RsMDMkYnRTZWFyY2jJnyPYjjwDsOatyCQBZar0ZSQygQ%3D%3D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24txtKeyword={company}&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24dpkTradeDate1%24txtDatePicker=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl03%24dpkTradeDate2%24txtDatePicker=&ctl00%24UcFooter2%24hdIP=&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=2E2252AF&__ASYNCPOST=true&'
    url=f'http://s.cafef.vn/Lich-su-giao-dich-{company}-1.chn'
    req=requests.post(url,data=send_param,headers={'User-Agent':User_Agent,'Content-Type':Content_Type})
    soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    reg1=re.compile('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl03_rptData2_ctl\d{2}_.*itemTR')
    a=soup.findAll('tr',{'id':reg1})
    b=[]
    for _val in a:
        c=[]
        for row in _val.findAll('td'):
            c.append(row.text)
        b.append(c)
    df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(b,columns=['Col'+str(i+1) for i in range(15)]))
    df['Company']=company
    return df
def get_data_all(company):
    df=pd.DataFrame({})
    for i in [j*200 for j in range(0,5)]:
        with threads.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
            results=[executor.submit(get_data,company,i) for i in range(i+1,i+201)]
            for result in threads.as_completed(results):
                df=df.append(result.result())
        if 0 in [len(results[i].result()) for i in range(len(results))]:
            break
    return df
```

Running get_data_all is equal to the combined time of the companies, not multithreading

```
t=time.perf_counter()
with threads.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
# results=[executor.submit(get_data_one,company) for company in lst_company]
# threads.as_completed(results)
    results1=[executor.submit(get_data_all,'DHG')]
    results2=[executor.submit(get_data_all,'VCB')]
    results3=[executor.submit(get_data_all,'MBB')]
time.perf_counter()-t
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't run multithreading"?  You're never going to have happiness running 600 threads at a time, but theoretically it should run.

Comment: Hey @Tim Roberts, sorry for the unclear question, I mean the get_data_all fuction I am expecting it to run at the same time to reduce the runtime, but when I run 3 companies it looks like a sequential (single thread) run, no improvement in terms of timing, while the get_data function is still running multithread fine (it's true that 600 threads are running at the same time for 3 companies but I'm just testing)

Comment: They obviously can't run at the same time unless you have 600 processors, which I doubt you do.  Your threads are going to be thrashing against each other, competing for the limited computing resources.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, maybe I don't understand threading correctly, but according to the above code I am hoping it is running at maximum 600 (max workers) for 3 companies ['DHG', 'VCB', 'MBB'], my machine is still running the result however does not improve the time on 2nd use of ThreadPoolExecutor because it is equal to time with not using ThreadPoolExecutor, I am suspecting it is not running at the same time, maybe my code is not correct, I need help help to perfect

Comment: Think about how this works.  At first, you have 200 units of work to be done.  At any given time. 4 of them are in processors, and 196 of them are blocked, waiting their turn.  Let's assume that you're achieving 100% CPU utilization.  In that case, there are no spare cycles for you to use.  If you go from 200 units of work to 600 units of work, it's going to take 3 times as long.  Threading can improve wall clock time when there are spare CPU cycles.  It cannot do so when you are CPU bound.

Comment: @Tim Robert's, thanks for your answers, I understand what you mean, 
I thought this is only affected by the calculations using the power of the CPU, and the web crawling problem depends on the Internet bandwidth, maybe because I use too much beyond the maximum limit of the cpu. Is there a way you can optimize for more time? , because when running 600 cpu workers only use 7% (equivalent to 1 thread of cpu), can multiprocess be a good solution?

Comment: Well, your internet bandwidth is not infinite, either.  Network connections take time.  I don't know for sure that's the case, but I suspect your performance issues are out of your control.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks for your help